# QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory в проводнике не отображаются подключенные устройства

Tags: c++, qt, explorer

У меня подключён телефон и он отображается в проводнике:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда пытаюсь открыть проводник с помощью кода в программе:

```
void IdentifyDevice::Explorer()
{
    QString path = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, tr("Открыть каталог"),
                                                    "/home",
                                                    QFileDialog::DontResolveSymlinks);
    DevicePathLineEdit->setText(path);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Apple iPhone устройства нет в "Устройства и диски".
Как отображать все устройства которые подключены в "Устройства и диски"?

Answer (score 1):

QFileDialog покажет только файловые(дисковые) устройства. Ваш телефончик ни тем ни тем не является.

Телефон это MTP устройство, и "общаться" с ним это уже совсем другая песня (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: Мне на qt form посоветовали делать через winapi, но получилось пока вывести названия подключённых устройств. Более конкретный ответ очень был бы кстати. Пример метода и библиотеки, для решения этой задачи, если есть то они очень бы помогли.

Comment: подобные вопросы есть в английской stackowerflow - поищите. и попробуйте поковыряйте например это https://github.com/ricohr/win-mtphelper

Comment: Tatarincev Спасибо .